# Variable substitution and the scale factor.

Tags: integration

When integrating some times its easier to substitute the variables to something else. In this case you have to make use of a Jakobian matrix and calculate the scale factor. I have a vague idea how the scale factor is compensating for the new form of the object.

But the question is. When calculating the scale factor for a rather common exchange of variables

$x = r \cos t, y = r \sin t$

the scale factor is $r$. But in other more general situations the calculated scale factor needs to be changed to :

$1/\text {scale factor}$

Why is that?